# Carpark calculation

Tags: c#

What I am attempting is, if hours are more than 8 charge the maximum fee, otherwise calculate the product of hours and the hourly rate. The hours must be rounded up. Eg if they enter 2.3 or 2.9 it needs to be rounded to 3.

It's pretty simple I know but Visual Studio says `parkTime` is a variable but used like a `method` and I'm stuck. Still a noob at C#.

In detail: The parking fee in a parking station is calculated on the whole number of hours (rounded up) multiplied by the hourly rate of $2.50.  The maximum parking fee is $20.00, e.g. parking for 4 hours yields a fee of $10.00, and parking for 10 hours yields a parking fee of $20.00 (i.e. the maximum fee).

My program is required to take hours input by keyboard and output the parking fee to the screen.

Note: Use ‘named constants’ rather than variables or literals for fixed amounts e.g.
const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.50;
const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal parkTime;  // input - time in hour eg 1.5 for 1 and hour hours 
        const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.50m;
        const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00m;
        decimal parkFee;
        Console.WriteLine("Time parked in hours: Eg 1.5 or 2.75");
        parkTime = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (parkTime > 8)
        {
            Console.Write("Total fee is $" + MAX_FEE);
        }
        else
        {
            parkFee = parkTime (Math.Ceiling) * HOURLY_RATE;
           Console.Write("Parking Fee = $" + parkFee);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(); // pause (before program ends) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your really want to round up the `HOURLY_RATE`? That does not make sense. I reckon you meant "the park time must be rounded up."

Answer (score 5):

You got the order wrong. It should be `Math.Ceiling(parkTime)`

Comment: it is not parkTime that should be ceiled it is the hourly_rate, imho that code line should be `parkFee = parkTime * Math.Ceiling(HOURLY_RATE);`

Comment: I don't think so. I believe OP wants to round the time entered by user to an integral number. Why would you declare a rate as a `decimal` only to round it later?

Comment: but isnt that what this sentence means? `The hourly rate must be rounded up. Eg if they enter 2.3 or 2.9 it needs to be rounded to 3.`

Comment: Which is why I said I believe the case to be the other way round. And if you notice, OP is assigning user input to `parkTime`.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - I don't think so either. But you are right, the question reads like this. I notified the OP.

Comment: Sorry guys have it wrong the parkTime need to be rounded up not the hourly rate which is const

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple syntax error. What should `parkTime (Math.Ceiling)` do? You want `Math.Ceiling(parkTime) * HOURLY_RATE`.

BTW: You could further simplify your code by using Math.Min:

```
parkTime = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

parkFee = Math.Min(8, Math.Ceiling(parkTime)) * HOURLY_RATE;
```

Since your `MAX_FEE` is equal to `8 * HOURLY_RATE`.

Comment: `Math.Max` or `Math.Min` you say one then use the other?

Comment: @DaveParsons - thanks, corrected. I always get confused because you want the value to be 8 maximum (at most), however to achieve that you need to use Math.Min to use 8 if 8 is smaller or the parkTime if the parkTime is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code even compile? asking cause of this line

`parkTime (Math.Ceiling) * HOURLY_RATE;`

shouldn't this be

```
Math.Ceiling(parkTime) * HOURLY_RATE;
```

Comment: Yes thanks this fixed the problem. Had it the wrong way around.
Sorry still new to all of this but thanks for you help

Comment: @user3615881, try accepting any one of the answer by clicking check button below voting button.